# Firestore pagination in a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, google-cloud-functions

I have implemented a "fetchFeed" cloud function where I do some kind of sql merge-join and manage complex business logic. Now, I am thinking of data pagination... but in a callable cloud function I can't store offsets, so, could it be good to pass it as data from the client? Is it normal to do it like this?

I mean, are cloud functions and data pagination compatible? Or would it better to handle all of this in the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could it be good to pass it as data from the client? Is it normal to do it like this?

Yup, that is the normal way to implement this. Since Cloud Functions are stateless, you'll need to pass all information from the client into the call.